# Defining data encoding of SMS messages in Android

Tags: android, encoding, sms, pdu, 7-bit

I'm working on an application using the SMS apis for android. The receiving end is an embedded unit that only supports 7-bit encoded SMS and the string I'm sending consists only of symbols from this particular alphabet which makes you think that Android is going to send it encoded as 7 bit. But that is not the case.

Therefore I'm searching for a way to specify what encoding to use. See below for what my code looks like today. The method gsm7BitPackedToString turns a byte-array to a 7-bit string, i.e. the string only consists of 7-bit compatible characters and is copied from the internal android api.

```
private static boolean sendMessage(String tel,byte[] message,int septets) {
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    if (septets != -1) {
        String a = GsmAlphabet.gsm7BitPackedToString(message,0,septets);
        sms.sendTextMessage(tel, null, a, null, null);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have considered the following solutions:

- Using some sort of internal method but none of the ones [I've read about](https://web.archive.org/web/20200222194635/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/11/calling-private-methods-in-android.html) seems to exist anymore.
- Sending a data message but this requires an additional User-Data Header that the receiving end also doesn't support.

Any help is appreciated :-)

Comment: Hi, Can you please add the classes or the link where did you find GsmAlphabet? I want to send SMS via USSD and I have problem with the encoding of the string I am sending in the ussd code. I can share my code for sending ussd message if you want. Thank you.

Comment: The GsmAlphabet is taken from the [android open source project](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=telephony/java/com/android/internal/telephony/GsmAlphabet.java;h=57d73e3758f5de2d52abc8deca66fd797f3a19e2;hb=HEAD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the solution wasn't as hard as it may seem. The GsmAlphabet class that I borrowed from the android project had some encoding bugs. I replaced it with the latest from the git repository and now it all seems to work like it is supposed to.

Lesson learned: Always double and triple check things that should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `SmsMessage` class:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html

Create `SmsMessage` object with `createFromPdu()` method and use it for sending in `SmsManager`.

I didn't try it. Good luck.

Comment: I've looked at that solution too. The problem I find is that there doesn't seem to be a way to actually send an instance of the SmsMessage class as an SMS. Maybe I'm just overlooking something...?